# How to get remote firewall administration working with Windows Server Core 2008 R2?

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2008-r2, windows, windows-server-core, remote-access

I'm setting up a Windows Server Core 2008 R2 installation in a VMware virtual machine before setting it up on a live VPS. I've gotten remote administration via MMC working on my computer (a PC running Windows 7) for things like event logs, but I can't seem to get the firewall administration working. No matter what I do, I get the following error mesage:

> You do not have the correct permissions to open the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security console. You must be a member of the Administrators group or the Network Operators group to perform this task. For more information, contact you system administrator. Error code: 0x5.

I've used `cmdkey` to add valid server credentials on my computer, and enabled remote management with the following commands:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="remote administration" new enable=yes
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="windows firewall remote management" new enable=yes
netsh advfirewall set currentprofile settings remotemanagement enable
```

I am **not** running on a domain (just a workgroup), this is the only Windows Server 2008 computer I have. I've tried turning off the firewall completely, but remote administration is still failing

How do I debug this issue? Does anyone know how to fix it?

I found a few forum topics about it (eg. [Remotely managing Windows Firewall on Server Core gives access denied (error 0x5) on Windows Server TechCenter](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservercore/thread/282f6be1-3330-46ca-b845-4c7d102f4e46/)) but they didn't help (I've already tried most of the fixes listed).

Comment: Any resolution for this issue?

Comment: @MilanGardian Nope, I never resolved this issue and I stopped using Windows Server.

Answer (score 2):

Your local user account needs to be identical to the server account if the server is not in a domain (same user / same pw). Apparently the Advanced Firewall snapin doesn't utilize the credentials you can store for the principal using cmdkey.

Answer (score 0):

try stopping the windows firewall service?

```
net stop mpssvc
```

Answer (score -3):

Stopping the windows firewall will just kill networking to the server completely.  Do not do this if you cannot access the machine console.

Comment: No it won't. It'll mean that the world and his mother can access your server.